# Fetch Results That Do not have relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `pools`, with id,name and a table called `alerts` which has id,poolid,create_date . I want to make an SQL query, which will bring me all the pools that DO NOT have a record on the `alerts` table with date equal to today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done in several ways, one of them is NOT EXISTS() :

```
SELECT * FROM pools p
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from alerts t
                 where t.poolid = p.id
                       and t.create_date < NOW())
```

Another way is NOT IN :

```
SELECT * FROM pools p
WHERE id NOT IN(select poolid from alerts t
                where t.create_date < NOW())
```

And if you wanna do it by joining :

```
SELECT p.*,t.id FROM pools p
LEFT OUTER JOIN alerts t
 ON(p.id = t.poolid and t.create_date < NOW())
WHERE t.id is null
```

Comment: Did a few minor changes and did the work, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join to get records from pools which don't have alerts:

```
select * from pools
left outer join alerts on pools.id = alerts.poolid
where alerts.id is null or alerts.created_date < now()
```

Comment: That is absolutly wrong, where is the ON clause? that won't even run, and you didn't compare anything to today's date. And why are you aliasing a table with the same name?? Its the same as not aliasing it

Comment: Copying the answers from peers and then downvoting their answers. That's the way to go, isn't it?

Comment: LOL, you are saying that I copied your INCORRECT answer? are you seriously accusing me on doing something so stupid?

Comment: I gave the OP all the options that he can do, you misdirected him. You gave him 1 incorrect answer that is not even formatted well, is this your first time programming in sql?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a query like this

```
select p.id,p.name 
from pools p
inner join alerts a on p.id=a.poolid
where date(a.created_date)!=date(sysdate())
```